# Awkward flickering on keyup search events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure if this is just the browser I'm using - or down to the script I've written (I'm a general 4/10 novice when it comes to Javascript, learning as much as I can) - but I get a weird flickering effect for a live search I've started to implement.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

  $('#search').keyup(function(){
    $('#result').html('');
    $('#state').val('');
    var searchField = $('#search').val();

    var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");

    $.getJSON('api/businesses', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.sector.search(expression) != -1) {
          $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="' + value.featured_image + '" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> '+ value.name + ' | <span class="text-muted">'+value.location+'</span></li>');
        }
      });
    });
  });

  $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
    $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
    $("#result").html('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="width:900px;">
   <h2 align="center">JSON Live Data Search using Ajax JQuery</h2>
   <h3 align="center">Employee Data</h3>
   <br /><br />
   <div align="center">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Employee Details" class="form-control" />
   </div>
   <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
   <br />
</div>
```

For the above snippet to work you'll need some sample data is json...might be easier to replicate locally.

Essentially - the search is working great, just seems very very jerky? Is anyone else seeing this, and if so, what can I do to improve this? N.B. I'm seeing this behaviour in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is clearing the html every time in **keyup** event.

```
$('#result').html(''); // <<< This guy
```

You should first filter in the results that you've found, and only if it's not there initiate a new api call.

Comment: It's a live search ... so every keyup needs something like this does it not? Could you advise even further :P

Comment: To expand on this, I'd suggest showing a loading spinner while the request is in progress, then only update the contents of the `#result` *after* the request is finished - either with the entries, or a message to the user explaining nothing was found.

Comment: You can save the searched data into a var. Now every time you press a key you will need to check inside that data if there is something related to in that var, exactly like you search on the received data. if not, initiate a new request, and again save the results into that var. You can also wrap it in setTimeout for a delay and cleartimeout when pressing another key. Also best practice is to set a minimum characters validation.

Comment: Additionally, it would be good to debounce the keyup events, so that if I (relatively quickly) type a word, it makes a _single_ AJAX call for the whole word, rather than 5 times (once for each letter I typed)

Comment: @cale_b How would I do that?

Comment: I guess I could wait until the user hits space or enter?

Comment: No, use a real debounce.  Here's one resource to help you build one: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function